# libOpenCL.so uses VFP register arguments, output does not

Tags: c++, arm, opencl

currently I am trying to build Buddhabrot for ARM architecture
but I am stuck at one point when I get the following error. I hope somebody can help.

```
libOpenCL.so uses VFP register arguments, output does not
libGAL.so uses VFP register arguments, output does not
```

here's my makefile

```
LIBS = -lm -lOpenCL -lGAL -lGL -lGLEW -lglut -lpthread
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
OBJECTS = main.o environment.o input.o animate.o buddhabrot.o buddhacl.o cmodules/timer.o
all: prog
prog: $(OBJECTS)
    c++ $(CFLAGS) -o prog $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
%.o: %.cpp $(LIBS)
clean:
    rm -f *.o prog cmodules/*.o
```

c++ -v output

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-    bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --    prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-float=softfp --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-    linux-gnueabi --target=arm-linux-gnueabi
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is telling you that libOpenCL.so and libGAL.so are using hard floating points and the [VFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Floating-point_.28VFP.29) unit, but your program is compiled to a program that uses soft floating points.

Use the `-mfloat-abi=hard` flag, and possibly `-mfpu=vfp` flag (see the gcc man page for other vfp variants that might be suitable).

If your platform doesn't support a hard float ABI, or your processor doesn't have a floating point unit, you cannot use these two libraries.

Comment: the gpu has a VFP unit
at least i compiled the following programm fine
https://github.com/laanwj/shoc

thaty why I am wondering why the above mentioned does not want to compile properly

Comment: To clarify the above answer, you might see this issue if the flags for the compiler and the linker don't match.

Answer (score 3):

your cross compiler dont support hard float, try arm-linux-gnueabihf instead,it works for me.

Comment: @fishiingMonster - wonderful answer! Do you know how to check if cross-compiler support hard float?