# Cross-compilation (ARM) 'VFP register arguments' error

Tags: compilation, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng

I want to build a DDS ['perftest'](https://community.rti.com/kb/example-performance-test-rti-message-service) application to do some tests between a x64  Kubuntu 15.10 and RaspberryPi 1 B, but in /rtiperftest.5.2.4/perftest_cpp directory there isn't a makefile for armv6 architecture.

I have installed crosstool-ng 1.22 to build application for target armv6 architecture following this [HOWTO (Section 4 and 5)](https://community.rti.com/content/forum-topic/howto-run-rti-connext-dds-raspberry-pi#Install_RaspberryPi_Libraries) but I didn't know how to write the makefile for build 'perftest_cpp'  using crosscompiler to run it on RaspberryPi.

Now I have got a makefile (attached) for build 'perftest_cpp' but I get **'uses VFP register arguments'** error (with hundred of files) that I can't understand (I only paste one error for make it readable)

```
/home/ampu/x-tools/armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/../../../../armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld.bfd: error: /opt/rti_connext_dds-5.2.3//lib/armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2/libnddscorez.a(SkiplistInfo.o) uses VFP register arguments, ../bin/armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2/Release/perftest_cpp does not 
/home/ampu/x-tools/armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/../../../../armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld.bfd: failed to merge target specific data of file /opt/rti_connext_dds-5.2.3//lib/armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2/libnddscorez.a(SkiplistInfo.o) 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
common2.mk:86: recipe for target '../bin/armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2/Release/perftest_cpp' failed 
make: *** [../bin/armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2/Release/perftest_cpp] Error 1
```

Here is my Makefile.RPi

```
ARCH         := armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2
DEBUG_FLAG   := -O4
#DEBUG_FLAG   := -g
#DEFINES_ARCH_SPECIFIC := -DRTI_LINUX

cxx_cc       := armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi-g++


cxx_ld       :=  armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabi-g++
cxx_ld_flags := -static-libgcc -ldl -lnsl -lm -L/usr/lib/nptl -lpthread -lrt

include common2.mk
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

---

**Attached files:**

[Makefile.RPi](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81sqi5zc67skg76/Makefile.i86RPi?dl=0)

[common2.mk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pt9bd02xriin48c/common2.mk?dl=0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libOpenCL.so uses VFP register arguments, output does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989766/libopencl-so-uses-vfp-register-arguments-output-does-not)

Comment: I have checked that question without positive results

Comment: Well, it's _exactly_ the same problem - you've compiled soft-float code and are trying to link it against hard-float libraries - so the onus is on you to describe _why_ this question is different and the accepted answer there doesn't apply.

Comment: By using  `-mfloat-abi=hard` flag and/or  `-mfpu=vfp` flag  not works for me, so I have not get positive results because the error persists with many variants of these flags.
Should I ask at the other question that you refer?

Comment: "Not working" always needs defining - either you get the _exact_ same result, which implies you've not changed things correctly, or you get _different_ errors (not excluding the same root cause showing up in different places), which would still be significant. I mean, I can _guess_ that you're also linking a soft-float libc from your toolchain so you face the same problem either way, but that really leads to a different question altogether. At this point, I'd just recommend you to follow step 5 of that tutorial, correctly.